# Is $(-\infty,\infty)$ a closed **interval**?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question, terminology

Note that we are working in the reals, not the extended reals. Now consider two opposing claims:

- $(-\infty,\infty)$ **is** a **closed interval**, because a closed
  interval is an interval that is a closed set.
- $(-\infty,\infty)$ is **not** a **closed interval**, because a closed
  interval is an interval that includes both its endpoints.

Recently, I was very surprised to be informed by several mathematicians that $(-\infty,\infty)$ ought to be called a closed interval, not an open interval. Perhaps I could get some consensus from this community, if possible.

p.s. To be very clear, I am *not* asking if $(-\infty,\infty)$ is a closed *set*—it sure is.

---

**Update**

For what it's worth, the [ISO 80000-2:2009 document](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf) explicitly calls $(a,b)$ an open interval and $[a,b]$ a closed interval.

Comment: There is another (better) definition saying that an interval (or more genreally any subset) is closed if it contains all its limit point. So in this case $(-\infty, \infty)$ is also closed.

Comment: @John Your definition is equivalent to the first one I gave (since closed sets are precisely the sets that include all their limit points).

Comment: @Rayan:- By $(-\infty,\infty)$ if you mean the whole real number set then it is both closed and open.

Comment: @Ryan: If an interval is a closed set then it is a close-interval! because an interval is either open-interval, hence an open set , otherwise a one-sided open-interval which is not a closed-set.

Comment: You have already answered your own question. If one accepts the first definition, then $\Bbb R$ is a closed interval. If one accepts the second definition, then $\Bbb R$ is not a "closed interval," although it is an interval that is a closed set. Both definitions are offered in practice. However the second definition creates the unfortunate and unintended circumstance that a closed interval is not a "closed interval." Thus, it is more technically sensible to accept the first definition. In practice, I believe the first is used more often by the more careful authors.

Comment: @SouvikDey Not so, if you are not using the first definition I offered. There is no right or wrong answer to my question, I am just trying to figure out which definition is more commonly accepted. Anon: This is why I have not answered my own question.

Comment: @Ryan It seems to me that the all the comments and answers understand closed interval as equivalent to closed set. If you're looking for consensus, or for which definition is more broadly used then I think you have your answer.

Comment: @anon I suppose the more careful writers will say that, e.g., the graph of $y=\sin x$ is a *simple closed curve*; because it's a curve, and it doesn't intersect itself, and it is certainly closed in the topology of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @bof LOL good point.

Comment: Regarding consensus ... It's worth noting that the mathematical community can't even agree on whether zero is a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

Comment: *"I was very surprised to be informed by several mathematicians that $(−\infty,\infty)$ ought to be called a closed interval, not an open interval"* ... Can you say something about the context(s) in which these several mathematicians offered their opinions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazing degree of consensus on the wrong answer. I won't bother giving my opinion (which I sort of hinted at in the previous sentence) because I am nobody and my opinion means nothing. Instead I will suggest a method you can use to get an answer, which may be slightly more valid than polling a handful of random internet addicts.

Go to the library and find the shelf with all the introductory analysis books. Look up the statements of theorems like "a continuous function on a finite closed interval attains its maximum" and "a continuous function on a finite closed interval is uniformly continuous". Count how many books include the word "finite" and how many omit it. I haven't done this myself, so I have no idea what result you will get.

Comment: I think the number of books that will omit the word "finite" when discussing theorems that need compact sets should be the empty set, thus the complement, this discussion, is closed. jk

Comment: @BradyTrainor Funny, somebody suggests an empirical approach to solve a question and you reply instantly that you do not need to do the experience because you know the answer. What happens if the data contradicts you? The data is wrong?

Comment: Well, when I hear "closed interval" I think [a,b]. But what do I know?

Comment: Precisely. I could accept allowing (−∞,∞) to be called a closed interval (since it is apparently not useful to insist otherwise, esp. in topology), but I would also point out that the notation indicates otherwise. Your suggestion to consider the extreme values theorem on the reals is excellent and convincing; you're the only person I've asked this question of today (not just on this website) to agree with the answer that I originally had thought was clear as ink. Apparently the earth is flatter than I had assumed.

Comment: BTW by this reasoning $[0,-1]$ is not a closed interval.