# Closed, Continuous, and Bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove or disprove this:

> Let $I$ be a closed interval. If $f\colon I\to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $I$, then $f$ is bounded on $I$.

Comment: No take $f:x\mapsto x$ and $I$ unbounded.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: When we refer to a closed interval, we always think of $[a, b]$ and not a closed set of real numbers like $(-\infty, \infty)$. There is a very good discussion on this at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543793/is-infty-infty-a-closed-interval

Comment: @Paramanand This is the first time I see this difference in definition I see that I was locked in my snail:-)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: When I read that linked question, I had the same feeling as you are having now. We have a lot to learn at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I$ is a closed *and bounded* interval then this is true. Without the boundedness assumption it is false (e.g. take the identity function).

To see why: suppose $I$ is a closed and bounded interval and $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is an unbounded continuous function. (Without loss of generality, $f$ is unbounded upwards.) For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, pick $x_n \in I$ with $f(x_n) \ge n$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ because it is a bounded sequence. By closure of $I$, $x^* = \lim_{j \to \infty} x_{n_j} \in I$. Derive a contradiction. (**Hint:** What is $f(x^*)$?)

Comment: Note: some *define* an interval to be bounded.

Comment: @dfeuer: I'd usually assume 'closed interval' implies bounded, but I wanted to cover all bases in case it really did mean 'interval which is a closed set'.

Comment: My text book defines it as 'interval is a closed set'

Comment: @dfeuer Right. Since $+\infty$ is not a real value, $[0,+\infty)$ can't be an inter-val ;-). Let's call these guys convex or connected and no confusion will be possible.

Comment: @julien: Intervals are often defined to be sets $I$ such that if $a,b \in I$ and $a<b$ then $c \in I$ for all $a<c<b$, in which case $[0,\infty)$ *is* an interval (and a closed set).

Comment: I know... and this definition is just convexity. I was just pointing out that the word "[inter-val](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))" was probably originally meant to describe what is between (inter) two val-ues.